# SeleniumScript to identify a css element

Tags: css, selenium

Title -I want to write a selenium script to identify the below css element background-image,id,style
css elements - {background-image: url("IMG?i=0aa0c09271b1f22009dc23e7b2a5b5e447a942c9&s=p"), style="visibility: visible; display: block; left: 24px; top: 8px; width: 12px; height}- its a green tick box

**Expected Result** i want to write a script to say if its with the above image its a pass else fail
Could anyone help me to write the selenium script
to satisfy my requirement

**css element**
{background-image: url("IMG?i=0aa0c09271b1f22009dc23e7b2a5b5e447a942c9&s=p"),
style="visibility: visible; display: block; left: 24px; top: 8px; width: 12px; height}

Comment: Please [Edit] your question with Relevant Html, Code trials and error stack if any?

Comment: what error stack u mean,, i want to identify a background tick box in my web and i am unbale to write the script